# Extend VBA range overflow

Tags: excel, vba

I want to read and store an Excel range in VBA for further manipulation. However when the range is larger than 256 x 65536 cells I get the Overflow error. Is it possible to read a large range? How is Big Grid concept implemented in VBA?

To clarify some of the comments and answers I am not counting the cells in the range, but trying to store it. It is Excel2010. The code is as follows

```
Dim rngRange as Range
rngRange = sheetName("Sheet1").Range(sheetName("Sheet1").Cells(1,1),sheetName("Sheet1").Cells(65537, 257))
```

Comment: Help us to help you..... **Post your code.**

Comment: Did you set the variable to long?

Comment: What version of Excel? Any version after 2003 or so should be able to handle over a million rows.

Answer (score 0):

A *Range* is a set of cells on a single worksheet.  The maximum number of cells in a range is given by:

```
=ROWS(A:A)*COLUMNS(1:1)
```

For Excel 2007 and later, this is 17,179,869,184 cells.  VBA can manipulate a range of this size.  For example:

```
Sub dural()
   Dim ReallyBigRange As Range, N As Double
   Set ReallyBigRange = Cells
   N = ReallyBigRange.CountLarge
   MsgBox N
   ReallyBigRange.Clear
End Sub
```

Comment: FWIW - a range can also be only a single cell